# In React, how can I add a copy-to-clipboard functionality, by writing a simple function without any files imported?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, clipboard, execcommand

I don't want import any files like [react-copy-to-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard).
I just want to use a simple JavaScript function, and it should work for **strings, values, states, props**, etc.

Comment: I have posted this question and I myself gave the answer, because this question will be raised in many react developers mind. It's not like what you think, I have done the research and through SO community,I am helping the developers who are in need @mthrsj

Comment: I haven't seen you answering the question. Congratulations for the initiative!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, we can do this in multiple ways, by importing files, which I would not recommend, because we import files only for bigger things.

The solution in general is given for a textarea or input type.

**Here is my solution which works for props, values, strings, states, or any other data type**

```
clipboardCopy() {
    var copyCode = document.createElement('textarea')
    copyCode.innerText = this.props.voucher_id //you can use props,states,values,strings. I just used props 
    document.body.appendChild(copyCode)
    copyCode.select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    copyCode.remove()
    this.toggleRegisterModal()
}
```

**You can use this solution in React, JavaScript, or in any other framework.**